# With RxJS how to trigger observables by another action stream

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, angular-reactive-forms

So I am trying to build a list component reactively by angular and RxJS.
the list has a lot of features like:

- search by word
- change page number
- change page size
- filter by field(s)
- sort

search service code:

```
private seachItemSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
private pageLimitSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(10);
private pageNumberSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
private orderingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<ListOrder>({});
private filteringSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

searchItemAction$ = this.seachItemSubject.asObservable();
pageLimitAction$ = this.pageLimitSubject.asObservable();
pageNumberAction$ = this.pageNumberSubject.asObservable();
orderingAction$ = this.orderingSubject.asObservable();
filteringAction$ = this.filteringSubject.asObservable();

combination$ = Observable.combineLatest(
    this.searchItemAction$,
    this.pageLimitAction$,
    this.pageNumberAction$,
    this.orderingAction$,
    this.filteringAction$
)

changeSeachItem(searchItem: string) {
    this.seachItemSubject.next(searchItem);
}

changePageLimit(pageLimit: number) {
    this.pageLimitSubject.next(pageLimit);
}

changePageNumber(pageNumber: number) {
    this.pageNumberSubject.next(pageNumber);
}

changeOrdering(listOreder: ListOrder) {
    this.orderingSubject.next(listOreder);
}

changeFilters(filters: any) {
    this.filteringSubject.next(filters)
}
```

Components code

```
results$: Observable<MyResult> = this.listSearchService.combination$
    .switchMap(([filterItem, pageLimit, pageNumber, ordering, filters]) => this.listService.query({
        offset: pageNumber,
        limit: pageLimit,
        filter: filterItem,
        order: ordering.order,
        descending: ordering.descending,
        ...filters
    }));
```

the problem that I am facing now is that I want the page number to be changed if the user used the filtering feature.

I think what I want is some sort of an Subject or an event that can be called whenever the user uses the filtering feature.

so it would be something like this.

```
applyFilters(filters: any) {
    this.listSearchService.changePageNumber(0);
    this.listSearchService.changeFilters(filters);
    this.listSearchService.commit.next() -----> so it would change both then start the combine latest
    console.log(filters)
}
```

I am not sure that that would be the right answer, so please tell me if you have a better answer.

Thanks

Comment: Compose your stream of page change events as a merge of the subject you have and an observable derived off of the filter change events. pageChange ::= manualPageChange + filterChange

Comment: I don't really understand, do u mind writing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered, you cannot use the original solution below as `combineLatest` will fire both when `changePageNumber` and `changeFilters` are called from `applyFilters`.

An alternative approach is to use a single state object implemented via the `scan` operator, and update one or more properties in it at a time. This means that the service firing from it will only be called once per 'action'.

BTW you are currently storing your 'state' in each BehaviorSubject, and combining it.

```
class ListState {
  searchItem: any = "";
  pageLimit: any = 10;
  pageNumber: any = 0;
  ordering: any = "asc";
  filtering: any = "";
}

const listStateUpdatesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Partial<ListState>>(null);
const listStateUpdates$ = listStateUpdatesSubject.asObservable();

// fires once per state update, which can consist of multiple properties
const currListState$ = listStateUpdates$.pipe(
  filter(update => !!update),
  scan<Partial<ListState>, ListState>(
    (acc, value) => ({ ...acc, ...value }), new ListState)
);

const callListService$ = currListState$.pipe(map(state => listService(state)));

function changeOrdering(listOreder: string) {
    changeState({ ordering: listOreder });
}

function changeFilters(filters: any) {
    changeState({ pageNumber: 0, filtering: filters }); // set both page number and filtering
}

// etc
```

Here is a working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-rxjs-filtering-2?file=index.ts, note that a call to `changeFilters` results in the service being called once only.

**Original Solution**

Create a new observable that listens to `filteringAction$`, perform the desired actions and use that new observable within the `combineLatest`.

```
...
orderingAction$ = this.orderingSubject.asObservable();
filteringAction$ = this.filteringSubject.asObservable();

filterApplied$ = filteringAction$.pipe(map(filter => applyFilters(filter)));

applyFilters(filters: any) {
  this.listSearchService.changePageNumber(0);
  this.listSearchService.changeFilters(filters);
  return filters;
}

combination$ = Observable.combineLatest(
  this.searchItemAction$,
  this.pageLimitAction$,
  this.pageNumberAction$,
  this.orderingAction$,
  this.filterApplied$    // instead of filteringAction$
)
```

Comment: filterApplied$ is now an observable<void>

Comment: @MFarahat see edited version above, it is now `Observable<any>` based on the type of the `filters` parameter passed into `applyFilters`.

Comment: it works now, but it sends the server 2 requests one canceled and one that goes through. is there a way to just make it in one call ? thanks

Comment: which service methods result in the server being called?

Comment: the server is being called by another service that is called from the component in this line
    results$: Observable<MyResult> = this.listSearchService.combination$
    .switchMap(([filterItem, pageLimit, pageNumber, ordering, filters]) => this.listService.query({

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the complete code, one possibility - have you included both `this.filteringAction$` and `this.filterApplied$` inside the `combineLatest`? You should have only `this.filterApplied$`.

Comment: I have only the filter applied