# rxjs - startWith based on Observable with initial value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have a data source with query, sort and pagination features. All of these are defined as BehaviourSubjects. I am trying to implement state saving the of the table, restoring the query, sort and pagination values.

Currently I have the code below that is responsible for it:

```
// params restored from storage
const pageSize = this.params.page?.pageSize ?? 20;
this.pageIndex = this.params.page?.pageIndex ?? 0;

query = new BehaviorSubject<Q | undefined>(params.query);
sort = new BehaviorSubject<Sort<T> | undefined>(params.sort);
page = new Subject<PageEvent>();
```

Code that manages data query:

```
combineLatest([this.query, this.sort])
.pipe(
  switchMap(([query, sort]) => this.page.pipe(
    // combine pageIndex: 0 for query, sort change
    startWith({ pageIndex: this.pageIndex, pageSize } as PageEvent), 
    map(page => [
      this.storeParams({ query, sort, page }),
      this.store.dispatch(
        this.selectAction({ query, page: page.pageIndex, sort, size: page.pageSize })
      )
    ]),
    catchError(error => of()),
  ))
);
```

It works properly but when sort or query values change, I need to reset pageIndex to 0. If I use startWith with pageIndex equal to 0, then I loose the ability to restore page values from storage.

To achieve it I reset the pageIndex on sort and query functions:

```
sortBy(sort: Sort<T>): void {
  this.pageIndex = 0; // need to remove
  this.sort.next(sort);
}

queryBy(query: Partial<Q>): void {
  this.pageIndex = 0; // need to remove
  this.query.next(query as Q);
}
```

How is it possible to achive this using a single operator, i.e. the combineLatest above?

Comment: Looks quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63440800/with-rxjs-how-to-trigger-observables-by-another-action-stream/63442653#63442653 which I have previously answered.

Comment: Thanks, but the solution you've mentioned is quite similar to mine. I just wanted to get rid of necessity to reset the pagination from sortBy\queryBy methods and to combine it inside the initial operator.

Comment: Your whole construct looks pretty convoluted. Why do you create your own inline operator instead of using switchMap? Why are you using switchMap with of instead of a normal map? Also, your stream depends on side effects anyways, so you can reset the value with a `tap` operator directly after `combineLatest`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Missed the first switchMap operator occasionally. Also the second map operator remained after several manipulations with the code. I've updated it for clearer understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work? Just reset pageIndex every time `combineLatest([this.query, this.sort])` has a new value.

```
combineLatest([this.query, this.sort]).pipe(
  tap(_ => this.pageIndex = 0),
  switchMap(([query, sort]) => this.page.pipe(
    // combine pageIndex: 0 for query, sort change
    startWith({ pageIndex: this.pageIndex, pageSize } as PageEvent), 
    map(page => [
      this.storeParams({ query, sort, page }),
      this.store.dispatch(
        this.selectAction({ 
          query, 
          page: page.pageIndex, 
          sort, 
          size: page.pageSize 
        })
      )
    ]),
    catchError(error => of()),
  ))
);
```